# ffmpeg работа с аудио потоком для encode

Tags: c++, c, аудио, ffmpeg

Пытаюсь написать encode с помощью библиотеки ffmpeg.

Ошибка заключается в том что при вызове функции `avcodec_open2`. Перед этим я выполнил все нужные настройки кодека но все же приведу весь свой код.

Мой класс :

```
class AudioFileWriter : public soundiocpp::InStream::IReader
{
public:
    explicit AudioFileWriter(const std::string filename, enum AVCodecID id, AVSampleFormat format, std::string aformat);
    ~AudioFileWriter() override;


private:
    void encode(enum AVCodecID id, AVSampleFormat f);
    int check_sample_fmt(const AVCodec *codec, enum AVSampleFormat sample_fmt);
    bool check_audio_format();
    int sample_rate_supported();
    int channel_layout();
    static void register_if_need();
    void openFile();
    AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *_format;
    std::string namef;
    std::string path;
    std::string audioFormat;
    AVFormatContext *s;
    AVOutputFormat *outFmt;
    AVFrame *frame;
    FILE *f;
    AVPacket pkt;
    char* output_formats[4] = { "mp3", "wav", "wma", "ogg" };

public:
    int availableReadFrames(int min, int max) override;
    void readSample(int channel, char *ptr, int size) override;
    void overflow() override;
    void readError(int err) override;
};
```

И главная функция в которой я проваливаюсь в ошибку:

```
void AudioFileWriter::encode( enum AVCodecID id, AVSampleFormat f )
{
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MP3);

    if (!codec)
        throw std::invalid_argument("This encoder is not available for this system!");

    _format = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!_format)
          throw std::invalid_argument("cannot allocate memory for AVFormatContext");
    _format->bit_rate = 128000;
    _format->sample_rate = f;

    _format->sample_rate = sample_rate_supported();
    _format->channel_layout = channel_layout();
    _format->channels = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(_format->channel_layout);


    if (avcodec_open2( _format,codec,NULL ) < 0)
        throw std::invalid_argument("cannot open codec");

    s = avformat_alloc_context();


    if ( !s )
        throw std::invalid_argument("cannot allocate media context");

    outFmt = av_guess_format(audioFormat.c_str(),NULL,NULL);
    if (outFmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)
    {
       throw std::invalid_argument("format fail");
    }

    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&s,outFmt,output_formats[1],NULL);

    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame)
         throw std::invalid_argument("Could not allocate audio frame");

    frame->nb_samples = _format->frame_size;
    frame->format = _format->sample_fmt;
    frame->channel_layout = _format->channel_layout;

}
```

Падаю в ошибку при вызове функции : `if (avcodec_open2( _format,codec,NULL ) < 0)`

Падаю на следующей ошибкой `Specified sample format -1 is invalid or not supported`

Comment: AVCodecContext есть поле time_base типа AVRational

Comment: А почему поток аудио а кодек x264?

Comment: @VTT да там мой косяк , там конечно будет другой формат

Comment: Лучше в начале открыть (создать) контейнер, который сам подберет соответствующий кодек, чем завадать кодек, а потом открывать контейнер - может быть несоответствие, на которое тоже надо реагировать

Comment: @VTT я исправил кодек , теперь появилась новая ошибка, взгляните одним глазом пожалуйста.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin про какой контейнер вы говорите ? про AVFormatContext ?

Comment: Да. Вот теперь у вас ошибка конфликт контейнера с кодеком, потому что wav не поддерждивает cжатие mp3 (не контейнер, а кодек), если я ничего не путаю. wav это контейнер для "сырых" данных

Comment: наверное надо выставить `_format->sample_fmt`, а заодно и прочие поля этой структуры, которые могут быть использованы целевым кодеком

Comment: Если для вас это не принципиально, то могу показать работающую схему записи данных в медиа-файл при помощи ffmpeg, вашу схему я не пробовал (то есть отдельно задавать и контейнер и кодек), ибо это черевато несогласованностью

Comment: @AlexanderChernin да если можно я был бы очень признателен.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin скинуть почту или вы дадите линк на какой то файлопомойник типо гитхаба?

Comment: На хаб еще не выложил, не до того пока. Сейчас напишу в виде ответа, поскольку оно еще немного сыровато, но пишет )

Comment: @AlexanderChernin спасибо

Comment: @AlexanderChernin вы про меня не забыли ?

Comment: Вы как раз вовремя. Готово )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Для версии ffmpeg 4 и выше**

Голова MediaWriter.h:

```
class AVFormatContext;
class AVCodecContext;
class AVStream;
class AVFrame;
class AVPacket;
class AVCodec;

class MediaWriter 
{
public:
    explicit MediaWriter();

    int start(const std::string& path);

    int initAudio(int* /*AVSampleFormat*/ sampleFormat, int* sampleRate, int64_t bitrate, int64_t channelLayout);
    int open();

    int write(MediaWriter::Type type, AVFrame* frame);
    int close();
private:
    int encode(AVCodecContext *codec_ctx, AVFrame *frame, AVPacket * packet);
    int free();

    AVFormatContext* fmt_ctx;
    struct Parameters
    {
        AVStream* stream;
        AVCodecContext* codec_ctx;
        AVCodec* _codec;
    };
    mutable Parameters _audioParams;
}
```

Реализация MediaWriter.cpp:

```
extern "C" {
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libswscale/swscale.h>
    #include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
    #include <libavutil/opt.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
}

MediaWriter::MediaWriter()
{
}

int MediaWriter::start(const std::string &path)
{
    return avformat_alloc_output_context2(&fmt_ctx, nullptr, nullptr, path.c_str());
}

int MediaWriter::initAudio(int *sampleFormat, int *sampleRate, int64_t bitrate, int64_t channelLayout)
{    
    AVCodecID codecId = fmt_ctx->oformat->audio_codec;
    if( codecId == AV_CODEC_ID_NONE )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    Parameters& p = _audioParams;
    p._codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codecId);
    if( !p._codec )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    p.stream = avformat_new_stream(fmt_ctx, p._codec);
    if( !p.stream )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    p.stream->id = fmt_ctx->nb_streams -1;
    p.codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(p._codec);
    if( !p.codec_ctx )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    p.codec_ctx->bit_rate = bitrate;
    p.codec_ctx->sample_fmt = static_cast<AVSampleFormat>(*sampleFormat);
    if( p._codec->sample_fmts )
    {
        p.codec_ctx->sample_fmt = p._codec->sample_fmts[0];
        for( int i = 0; p._codec->sample_fmts[i]; i++ )
        {
            if( p._codec->sample_fmts[i] == *sampleFormat )
            {
                p.codec_ctx->sample_fmt = static_cast<AVSampleFormat>(*sampleFormat);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    p.codec_ctx->sample_rate = *sampleRate;
    if( p._codec->supported_samplerates )
    {
        p.codec_ctx->sample_rate = p._codec->supported_samplerates[0];
        for( int i = 0; p._codec->supported_samplerates[i]; i++ )
        {
            if( p._codec->supported_samplerates[i] == *sampleRate )
            {
                p.codec_ctx->sample_rate = *sampleRate;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    *sampleRate = p.codec_ctx->sample_rate;
    p.codec_ctx->channel_layout = channelLayout;
    p.codec_ctx->channels = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels( p.codec_ctx->channel_layout );
    p.stream->time_base = {1, *sampleRate};

    if (fmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        p.codec_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

    return 0;
}

int MediaWriter::open()
{
    Parameters& p = _audioParams;
    int ret = avcodec_open2(p.codec_ctx, p._codec, nullptr);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        return ret;
    }

    ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(p.stream->codecpar, p.codec_ctx);
    if( ret < 0 )
    {
        return ret;
    }

    if (!(fmt_ctx->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    {
        ret = avio_open(&fmt_ctx->pb, fmt_ctx->url, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            return ret;
        }
    }

    return avformat_write_header(fmt_ctx, /*&opt*/nullptr);
}

int MediaWriter::write(AVFrame *frame)
{
    if( frame == nullptr )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    Parameters& p = _audioParams;
    AVCodecContext* context = p.codec_ctx;
    AVStream* stream = p.stream;

    if( context && stream )
    {
        AVPacket pkt;
        av_init_packet(&pkt);
        int ret = encode(context, frame, &pkt);

        if( ret != 0 )
        {
            return ret;
        }

        av_packet_rescale_ts(&pkt, context->time_base, stream->time_base);
        pkt.stream_index = stream->index;

        ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt);
        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
        return ret;
    }

    return -1;
}

int MediaWriter::close()
{
    if( fmt_ctx )
    {
        int error = av_write_trailer(fmt_ctx);
        if( error != 0 )
        {
            return error;
        }
    }

    return free();
}

int MediaWriter::encode(AVCodecContext *codec_ctx, AVFrame *frame, AVPacket *packet)
{
    if( frame->format < 0 )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int error = avcodec_send_frame(codec_ctx, frame);
    if (error < 0)
    {
        return error;
    }

    return avcodec_receive_packet(codec_ctx, packet);
}

int MediaWriter::free()
{
    if( fmt_ctx != nullptr )
    {
        if( !(fmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE) )
        {
            int ret = avio_closep(&fmt_ctx->pb);
            if( ret != 0 )
            {
                return ret;
            }
        }

        avformat_free_context(fmt_ctx);
        fmt_ctx = nullptr;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
MediaWriter writer;
writer.start("<путь/к/создаваемому/файлу_с_раширением>"); 
// по расширению система выбирает соответствующий кодек и 
// делает другие необходимые настройки

int sampleFormat = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16; // Как пример, сэмплы знаковые целочисленные 2-х байтовые
int sampleRate   = 44100;
int bitrate = 4000000;
int layout  = 2;
// аргументы передаются через указатель, потому что
// либа может их изменить на те, которые больше подходят для
// корректной работы с кодеком.   
writer.initAudio(&sampleFormat, // AVSampleFormat
                 &sampleRate,   // например 22050, или 44100 и так далее
                  bitrate,      // битрейт, напирмер 4000000
                  layout);      // моно, стерео... 1,2,5 и так далее

if( writer.open() != 0 )
{
    // Ошибка...
}

// Цикл записи данных
int pts = 0;
while(/*какое-то условие*/)
{
    AVFrame* frame = ... //откуда-то получаем "сырые данные" для сохранения
    frame->pts = pts++; // время показа кадра в единицах AVStream::time_base
    frame->pkt_duration = 1; // Длительность кадры (можно не указывать, но бывает)

    // Передаем сырые данные в метод write
    // там они сжимаются (encode) и 
    // сохраняются av_interlived_write_frame
    writer.write(frame);
}

writer.close();
```

Пробуйте. Критика приветствуется.

З.Ы. Если нужны пояснения, то готов дополнить код комментариями

Comment: Спасибо , сейчас буду разбираться и если что отпишусь. Очень выручили

Comment: AVFormatContext* fmt_ctx. Что то я не понимаю по поводу строки ret = avio_open(&fmt_ctx->pb, fmt_ctx->url, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE); именно в fmt_ctx->url, у меня отсутствует поле

Comment: @jNX а версия либы ffmpeg у вас какая? url появился в 4-й. Можно вместо url попробовать  указать filename

Comment: libavutil-dev:
  Установлен: 7:3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 
да у меня версия ниже

Comment: а указывать имя файла без расширения ? например test или test.wav. P.S Увидел , с расширением

Comment: @jNX если без расширения, то либа не поймет какой кодек подтягивать. В этом случае надо второй параметр функции указывать

Comment: пытаюсь вот разобраться и не понял в // Цикл записи данных
int pts = 0;    зачем это нужно , что то я нагуглить нормальное объяснения не могу

Comment: @jNX для того, чтобы кадры сохранялись/воспроизводились по-порядку. PTS - Presentation Time Stamp - время показа кадра в единицах AVStream::time_base

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90992/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and-jnx).

Comment: А можешь еще мне на пару вопросов ответить ) Я чат сам не могу создать